# 2V voltage drop like a LED

Tags: led, voltage

I am planning to control 8x 7-segments LED displays ([Kingbright SC15-11EWA](http://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/spec/SC15-11EWA.pdf)) with a [MAX7221 Serially Interfaced, 8-Digit LED Display Driver](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf). However, as you can see in the datasheet, the SC15-11EWA has only one LED for the dot whereas it has 2 for the other segments, but the MAX7221 has only one lightness/current control for all the segments.

In order to fix the dot point dissymmetry, I would like to add a 2V voltage drop device that would be common to all the displays' dot points. For now, I use a orange LED with mask tape on it, but I'm worried about durability, especially if all points are on : it should receives 160mA (if I'm not mistaken) and so it will burn very soon.

I was thinking about using a 2V zener instead, but don't find one easily available through-hole with enough current rating.

Is there another solution? What do you recommend to fix the dissymmetry in my case?

Comment: How about links to the data sheet and display.

Comment: If the MAX7221 is a true current source, then you don't need any extra components at all. The driver itself will "absorb" the extra voltage.

Comment: Why do you think the external LED would burn out any faster than the 'dot' LED of the display? As a multiplexed device the current is not continuous and will not overheat the LED causing it to fail prematurely.

Comment: @JimDearden: I didn't made myself clear: I have wired only 1 LED to the common point of the dot segments, so it receives the sum of the currents that each dot receive, that is much more than 20mA on average

Comment: @DaveTweed: this is not a true current source (see graph 2 on page 4), but as johnfound states, this may be acceptable

Comment: I'll try to short my orange LED to see if the difference in current/lightening is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The Maxim MAX7221 provides constant current source and sink for every segment of every digit, set by the resistor R<sub>set</sub> that must be connected between the I<sub>set</sub> pin and V<sub>DD</sub>. First thing to check is if that resistor has been connected, and if so, whether it is correctly calculated for the desired current per LED.

Regardless of the number of LEDs in series, as long as the supply voltage is sufficiently higher than the forward voltage of the combination of LEDs, the current through the segment (or the dot) will be constant. In other words, the MAX7221 output pins will automatically provide different voltages for the single-LED and the double-LED current paths.

As LED intensity is related to current through it and not voltage, if any difference in intensity is observed is most likely due to difference in the optical behavior of the light-pipes used for the digit segments and the dot segment.

Adding an extra masked out LED on each of the dot connections will not expose those LEDs to 160 mA as stated in the question, but to the same current as each of the other segments is set to, via RsetM/sub>. Thus, if it provides any satisfaction, one can go ahead and add those extra LEDs in series without a problem.

Despite what another answer claims, the datasheet for the LED display clearly states:

> Forward Voltage Per Segment Or (DP)       4.0 (2.0)

This means the forward voltage of the number segments is 4.0 Volts typical, while that of the dot segment is 2.0 Volts typical. Thus, the contention that the number segments are 2 LEDs each, and the dot is a single LED, is perfectly valid. It doesn't affect intensity when using constant current driving, through.

Comment: I was just taking a further look into it (deleted my comment about a resistor) but did you notice on page 12 they have an example of using a zener for different forward voltage drops? Reading between the lines in the datasheet it doesn't seem too sophisticated unless I've missed something.

Comment: @PeterJ That's needed for external transistor drive. From the datasheet: *The example in Figure 2 uses the MAX7219/MAX7221’s segment drivers, a MAX394 single-pole double-throw analog switch, and **external transistors** to drive 2.3 inch AND2307SLC common-cathode displays.*

Comment: @PeterJ Having suffered the MAX7219 series on multiple projects, I detest it pretty strongly: The sucky external drive current control mechanism is just one of the reasons.

Comment: I added a comment to my question to make myself clear: the masked LED is wired to the common point of the dot connections, so it is shared by all the digits, thus my question

Comment: @SylvainPrat So wire the masked LED to the line feeding the DP segment instead. Problem solved - not that there should have been a problem in the first place :-)

Answer (score 0):

MAX7221 has **constant current outputs**, so the current in the segments does not depend (highly) by the LED voltage!

According to the data sheet, using Rset = 20kOhm, the output current on the 4V output voltage (segment) will be 20mA and on 2V output voltage (decimal point) will be 25mA.

This difference is acceptable in my opinion.

Comment: The LED display datasheet both shows a schematic with 2 LEDs for segments a-g and a single LED for DP, and explicitly provides different forward voltages of 4.0 and 2.0 typical, 5.0 and 2.5 maximum, respectively for them.

Comment: So, I read another data sheet...

Comment: I'll try to short my orange LED to see if the difference is acceptable.